# Antique glass door mounted as room divider in apartment

Tags: drywall, doors, mounting

I am moving into a rental apartment. It is a one bedroom so 8 need to put my home office in the living room. I found an antique glass panel door I’ve painted and want to use as a room divider .
Is it possible to mount it to the drywall wall with a hinge to fold closed sometimes securely? What kind of prep, mounting hardware and hinges would be appropriate?

Comment: Drywall itself will not hold that door.  You would be lucky to get two swings with it.  You will need at least a 1x4 screwed into studs to mount the hinges and a door stop. This is the minimum, it should be done better.  I would talk with the landlord before doing this, since you will need to leave the door up when leaving or repair the wall.

Comment: Newly installed glass doors are required to be made of tempered glass in most jurisdictions, identifiable by permanent marking as "TEMPERED". Check with your local authority. If you create a violation, your landlord can be penalized, and they can come after you when you leave the apartment.

Comment: This sort of thing is typically better done with a freestanding folding divider. A glass panel door is likely to be a bit heavy and awkward, by comparison.

Comment: It would help to understand the layout of the apartment, as well as the size and weight of the door and how it operates.

Comment: @MTA I am not sure this applies. Won't the building code distinguish between the permanent fixtures and stuff the resident just adds? I agree a door is weird, but I imagine an inspector would roll their eyes and not fault the property management. I agree it depends from place to place. My state has a lot of "assumed risk" clauses about letting people do potentially dumb things.

Comment: @AdamO It's unclear. The OP wants to attach it to a wall with hinges, which makes it a permanent fixture by any reasonable interpretation. Free standing makes it furniture. But is it a door or a room divider? The OP wrote "to fold closed sometimes securely" which might be to use the door as a door. But who knows? Without feedback, it's all speculation. The takeaway, though, is to know the legal risks before installing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.